# ubuntu version 1610 will not print to a samsung laser printer

Tags: printing

The problem in a nutshell, the printer from Samsung ML-2545 (laser printer)
worked perfectly on ubuntu version 1510. I installed new version 1610, selected
the printer from the system setting's dialog and everything seemed ok.
I test print from inside the dialog, nothing. Not really nothing, the
printer woke up like normal (ready to print like) and shortly after, the 
printer went back to sleep. No output. have tried this on text files
pdf files with exactly the same result.

I have a mulifunction hp printer HP Officejet Pro 8625 connected as a network
printer. Using the same system printing app, loaded the driver and appeared
on the app display. That works perfectly printing many files. So the cups
software is correctly installed i think.

I turned the debug on from the cups config file, and gave me lots of output
in a file error_log with the error:
  HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe).

In reading cups info, it is supposed to take the file, run it thru some 
filters (filters depend one the file that is printed) and the instructions 
inside the printer driver).

```
The following lines seem ok to me::
-----------------------------------
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] cupsdIsAuthorized: username="root"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] argv[0] = "/usr/lib/cups/daemon/cups-deviced"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] argv[1] = "1"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] argv[2] = "0"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] argv[3] = "2"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] argv[4] = "7"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] argv[5] = "requested-attributes=all exclude-schemes=\'beh\',\'cups-pdf\',\'bluetooth\',\'dnssd\',\'http\',\'https\',\'lpd\',\'ncp\',\'parallel\',\'scsi\',\'smb\',\'snmp\',\'socket\'"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[0] = "CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[1] = "CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[2] = "CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[3] = "CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[4] = "CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[5] = "CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[6] = "CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[7] = "CUPS_STATEDIR=/var/run/cups"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[8] = "HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[9] = "PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[10] = "SERVER_ADMIN=root@coco"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[11] = "SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.2.0"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[12] = "TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[13] = "USER=root"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[14] = "CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[15] = "CUPS_SERVER=/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[16] = "CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[17] = "IPP_PORT=631"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[18] = "AUTH_TYPE=PeerCred"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[19] = "LANG=en_US.UTF8"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[20] = "REDIRECT_STATUS=1"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[21] = "GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[22] = "SERVER_NAME=localhost"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[23] = "SERVER_PORT=631"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[24] = "REMOTE_ADDR=localhost"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[25] = "REMOTE_HOST=localhost"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[26] = "SCRIPT_NAME=/"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[27] = "SCRIPT_FILENAME=/usr/share/cups/doc-root/"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[28] = "REMOTE_USER=root"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[29] = "SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[30] = "HTTP_USER_AGENT=CUPS/2.2.0 (Linux 4.8.0-34-generic; x86_64) IPP/2.0"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[31] = "REQUEST_METHOD=POST"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[32] = "CONTENT_LENGTH=236"
D [24/Jan/2017:20:30:36 -0700] [CGI] envp[33] = "CONTENT_TYPE=application/ipp"


Following ubuntu recipe for debugging cups.
--------------------------------------------

    DebuggingPrintingProblems

david@coco:~$ 
david@coco:~$ lsmod | grep usb
usblp                  20480  0
snd_usb_audio         184320  1
snd_usbmidi_lib        32768  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hwdep              16384  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio
snd_pcm               110592  6 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_rawmidi            32768  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
snd                    86016  28 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
usbhid                 53248  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
usb_storage            73728  2 uas
david@coco:~$ 
david@coco:~$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Jan 24 20:42:15 coco gvfsd[1659]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Jan 24 20:42:15 coco gvfsd[1659]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Jan 24 20:42:15 coco gvfsd-recent[5086]: cannot open display: 
Jan 24 20:42:15 coco gvfsd[1659]: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Jan 24 20:43:01 coco nautilus[2286]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
Jan 24 20:44:41 coco unity-panel-ser[2179]: window_menu_model_new: assertion 'BAMF_IS_APPLICATION(app)' failed
Jan 24 20:44:41 coco unity-panel-ser[2179]: track_menus: assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(menus)' failed
Jan 24 20:47:15 coco unity-panel-ser[2179]: menus_destroyed: assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(wm)' failed
Jan 24 20:47:21 coco zeitgeist-datah[2648]: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:212: Error during inserting events: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.zeitgeist.EngineError.InvalidArgument: Incomplete event: interpretation, manifestation and actor are required
Jan 24 20:47:21 coco unity-panel-ser[2179]: menus_destroyed: assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(wm)' failed


^C
david@coco:~$ 
david@coco:~$ lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e8:3315 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd ML-2540 Series Laser Printer
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0480:d010 Toshiba America Inc External Disk 3TB
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:0809 Logitech, Inc. Webcam Pro 9000
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 062a:3621 Creative Labs 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
david@coco:~$ 
david@coco:~$ ls -l /dev/usb/lp* /dev/bus/usb/*/*
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   0 Jan 24 19:28 /dev/bus/usb/001/001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   1 Jan 24 19:28 /dev/bus/usb/001/002
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   2 Jan 24 19:28 /dev/bus/usb/001/003
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   3 Jan 24 19:30 /dev/bus/usb/001/004
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   4 Jan 24 19:30 /dev/bus/usb/001/005
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189,   5 Jan 24 19:30 /dev/bus/usb/001/006
crw-rw-r-- 1 root lp   189,   6 Jan 24 20:30 /dev/bus/usb/001/007
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 128 Jan 24 19:28 /dev/bus/usb/002/001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 256 Jan 24 19:28 /dev/bus/usb/003/001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 384 Jan 24 19:28 /dev/bus/usb/004/001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 512 Jan 24 19:28 /dev/bus/usb/005/001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 640 Jan 24 19:28 /dev/bus/usb/006/001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 768 Jan 24 19:28 /dev/bus/usb/007/001
crw-rw---- 1 root lp   180,   1 Jan 24 20:30 /dev/usb/lp1
david@coco:~$ 
david@coco:~$ sudo usb_printerid /dev/usb/lp0
[sudo] password for david: 
Error: No such file or directory: can't open '/dev/usb/lp0'
david@coco:~$ sudo usb_printerid /dev/usb/lp1
GET_DEVICE_ID string:
MFG:Samsung;CMD:SPL,FWV,EXT;MDL:ML-2540 Series;CLS:PRINTER;STATUS:BUSY;
david@coco:~$ 
david@coco:~$ lpinfo -v
network beh
network https
serial serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
network ipp14
network socket
network ipps
network lpd
network http
network ipp
direct usb://Samsung/ML-2540%20Series?serial=Z6FJBKDC101165D.
direct hp
direct parallel:/dev/lp0
direct hpfax
david@coco:~$
```